# Compiling applications from shared folders in a VM

Tags: file, compilation, virtual-machine, vmware

I currently have many Linux VM's set up on VMware Workstation, there are some shared folders that contain source code that is held on the host computer. The issue I am having is that whenever I try to compile a file by using any compiler I get an Illegal seek error and file not recognized. Is there any way around this? I am using an Ubuntu 64-bit VM with Windows 7 as the host and the location of the shared files are on the Windows 7 hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into a number of problems doing development over a network share in the past and suggest rather than sharing the files via SMB, you'll find more luck if you check in/out the files from a source control system (or simply copy them) so they're on a "local" drive on both the guest and host.

Comment: It actually turns out that it was 11.04 ubuntu and vm-ware tools not getting along because it works just fine in arch, bsd, and 10.10 ubuntu on my vms

Comment: Although this is a good option (I just didn't want to have to make multiple copies of the same thing across host and guest OS)